# Refer to variables in go using the data in other variables?

Tags: variables, go

I am relatively new to go/ coding.I want to be able to reference a variable by using a variable.

```golang
var a = make([]int,0)
var b = make([]int,0)
var c = make([]int,0)
```

I have some slices defined

```golang
set := input.Ask("Which set would you like to input to (a, b, c):")
for true {
  num := input.Ask("Number:")
  strings.toLower(set) = append(strings.toLower(set), num)
}
```

I want the "strings.tolower" part output a string, which it does, that will allow me to select one of the variables I have defined.

Comment: FYI, `x := make([]T, 0)` can usually be replaced with `var x []T`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like the general description of a *string-keyed map*: you have three values, and you want to choose which one to use based on some string value.

```
maps := map[string][]int{}

set := input.Ask("Which set would you like to input to:")
set = strings.toLower(set)
for true {
    num := input.Ask("Number:")
    maps[set] = append(maps[set], num)
}
```

If it's important to you to only be able to use one of these three values, you can prepopulate the map

```
maps := map[string][]int{
    "a": nil,
    "b": nil,
    "c": nil,
}
set := input.Ask("Which set would you like to input to (a, b, or c):")
set = strings.toLower(set)
if _, ok := maps[set]; !ok {
    fmt.Println("I don't know about that set")
    return
}
```

There's [more information on maps in the language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types).

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
var selected *[]int
switch strings.ToLower(set) {
  case "a": selected = &a
  ...
}
*selected = append(*selected, num)
```